# Rspec getting undefined method error when I try to use fill_in on text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Totally revising this question, since I fixed the first issue but have ran into a new one.  My code now looks like this-

```
it 'should return on a partial match of Subject ID' do
  visit newpatient_path
  fill_in :subject_id, :with => "0303"
  click_button "Find Patient"
  response.should redirect_to(searchresult_path())
end
```

When I run this I get the following error-

```
  Patients SEARCH patient should return on a partial match of Subject ID
 Failure/Error: fill_in :subject_id,    :with => "0303"
 Webrat::NotFoundError:
   Could not find field: :subject_id
 # ./spec/requests/patients_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

subject_id is the text_field value for the field in question.  Not sure why I can't find it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I revised the question, since I answer the original one within a few minutes of posting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no Webrat expert, but doesn't the `fill_in` method expect a String as its first argument? You are passing a Symbol; don't know whether that's allowed.

Comment: I had passed a symbol elsewhere, but after some fiddling I was able to get it to take 'patient[subject_id]' and be happy- I think this was a path issue- so much I am still learning.  Thanks!